# Angularjs 1.3.1 ng-repeat css animation nothing happens

Tags: css, angularjs, animation

Just starting with the Angularjs framework and i'm overlooking something. I made a simple css animation [plunker][1] and nothing happens?! Any help? Thanx in advance!

[1]: http://plnkr.co/edit/Qmox56AFYRDwfDPli38X`enter code here`

Comment: You missed to add ngAnimate in your app dependencies

Comment: That is right, overlooked that too ;). Added cdn for the dependency and changed the js script, But still not working :(. Thnx anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add ngAnimate and it works fine

plnkr.co/edit/zyqaM1

Comment: So, the animations only occur after the page has loaded and events after loading the page? Not by rendering the ng-repeat? It seems clear to me.. I'm new to Angular, but that's obvious ;). thnx